# Show content as per Taxonomy Term

Tags: theming, nodes, taxonomy-terms

I am new to `drupal` and using `drupal 7`. I have created some `taxonomies` and using it as menus using [Taxonomy Menu](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) module. The Taxonomies are being shown as menus.

Now I want to change content of the page as per term of the taxonomy. I have searched the problem but found different modules doing this task like [Taxonomy Display](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_display), [Taxonomy Menu Block](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu_block). But I don't want  to use any of the module and want to do it manually so that I can understand the inner working of `Drupal themes`.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to filter contents on node page on basis of term associated with current node?

Comment: @PushpinderRana Yup I want to change content of my main page on basis of term associated.

Comment: Using VIEWS you can achieve it. Associate a node with the term and create a new VIEW and add a relationship to get all the details based on the relationship.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views):

1. Create view of block type (`admin/structure/views`)
2. Add fields want to display on term page.
3. Go to "Contextual filters" settings under "Advanced" tab.
4. Add the filters: "Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)" and "Content: Has taxonomy term ID depth modifier". You can configure this on this filter: → When the filter value is NOT in the URL: → Provide default value → Type: Taxonomy Term ID from URL → under that, check the box "Load default filter from node page, that's good for related taxonomy blocks." → now check the boxes of the taxonomies you want involved here.
5. Now you need to add the second filter in order to exclude the current node from the list. Click [+] button of the contextual filters section.
6. Select Content: Nid.
7. Chosse the option "when argument is not present" to "Provide default argument".
8. Choose the "Default argument type" to "Content ID from URL".
9. Go to "MORE" , and check the "Exclude" box.
10. Move the filter "Content: Nid" to the top position.
11. Add a block to your view and embed the block on your node pages.
12. Save your view

[image]